# Python while loop , how can I reach a given list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, while-loop

```
items = ['apple', 55, 1.2, 'banana', lambda a: a, 
     'pear', None, 'cherry', """Hello world!""",
     '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]

i = ""

while i in items:
if(items == type(str)):
    print("There are 6 string")
if(items != type(str)):
    print("There ara no string value")
```

I've written this program but it's not working.
How can I reach the list and print how much string in this list also with `type()` method?

After;
since there are multiple string values in the input list. However, in case there are no string values, your program should output

`There are no string values`

In case there is only one string value, then it should print out

`There is a single string value.`

İt's my homework but I'm stuck at this question.
Also, can I do with for loop?

Comment: `print('There are {} string items in the list'.format(sum(1 for item in items if isinstance(item, str))))`

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking a few details - Can there be multiple `list`s within the `items` list? Even if there is a single `list` within `items` - what should the output be if there are multiple strings?

Comment: @Chris_Rands , it's worked actually but ı have to use type(.) method. with a while loop.

Comment: @Mortz, 
Write a Python program that uses a `while-`loop to count and print out how many `str` (string) values a given list contains _at the top level_. For example, when you run your program over the following list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want to do is this:

```
items = ['apple', 55, 1.2, 'banana', lambda a: a, 'pear', None, 'cherry',  """Hello world!""", '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]

i = 0

for item in items:
   if(type(item) == str):
       i += 1

print(f'There are {i} string' if i > 0 else "There are no string values")
```

Comment: yes this is what ı want. Thx a lot and now ı'm gonna write with while loop.